# Warnings when saving a figure with `matplotlib`

Tags: python3, gtk, matplotlib

I have a simple `matplotlib` script:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], c="b")
plt.savefig("./fig.png")
```

When I run the script, the image is saved okay, but I get the following warnings:

```
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
Gtk-Message: 10:29:05.912: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
```

Following [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/uopua4/comment/jp2jiko/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I ran `python3 -m pip install pyqt6`, which made the `QSocketNotifier` warning go away, but I still get the `Gtk-Message` warning. Any ideas on how to make it go away? Following [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/f7zafc/comment/fihrl2k/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I already tried `sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module`, and again with `--reinstall`, but it didn't help. I get the same warning if I use `plt.show()` instead of `savefig`.

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Python 3.10.12, matplotlib 3.8.2